# SQL for messages

Tags: mysql, join

Hello I have a table messages and I want to display a conversation-style inbox (just like gmail) conversation order by date and grouped by user

table messages

- from_user_id
- to_user_id
- message
- read
- from_user_deleted
- to_user_deleted

users table

- id
- username

this is my SQL query to get all messages received or sent by me (user: 1)

UPDATED QUERY!

```
    SELECT 
        account_id,
        accounts.username,
        status,
        content
    FROM
        ((SELECT
                id,
                to_id AS account_id,
                content,
                status
        FROM messages
        WHERE from_id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC)
      UNION
        (SELECT
                id,
                from_id AS account_id,
                content,
                status
        FROM messages
        WHERE to_id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC)
      ) AS messages, accounts 
      WHERE accounts.id = account_id AND accounts.deleted = 0
    GROUP BY 
        account_id
    ORDER BY messages.id DESC
```

Now I´m getting more accurate results. how can i make sure that the query is returning the LAST message sent for each conversation? thanks!

Comment: have you tried using `join`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT messages.*,from_users.username as Sender,
       to_users.username as Reciever
       FROM messages 
       INNER JOIN users from_users ON from_users.id = messages.from_user_id
       INNER JOIN users to_users ON to_users.id = messages.to_user_id
    WHERE messages.from_id = 1 OR messages.to_id = 1
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 0,10
```

This might be what you want.

But i want to point out something in your structure.

As you said

> "the from_user_id because to_user_id will allways be the logged in user"

The above statement will be true only if you have a `conversation_id` in your table.

In that case `the from_user will be the the logged in user for a conversation_id`.

If you change the table `"messages"`structure as below ,

- from_user_id
- conversation_id
- to_user_id
- message
- read
- from_user_deleted
- to_user_deleted

then this query can be used to find the sender and reciever in different conversation.

```
SELECT messages.*,from_users.username as Sender,
           to_users.username as Reciever
           FROM messages 
           INNER JOIN users from_users ON from_users.id = messages.from_user_id
           INNER JOIN users to_users ON to_users.id = messages.to_user_id
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 0,10
        GROUP BY conversation_id
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That´s correct. I only have a messages table (no conversations table). I generate the conversations based on messages (groups of messages between two users)

Comment: if it helpful..and if you got what youwant, please mark as answer.

Comment: the query is not grouping by conversation. is returning duplicate users instead of returning the last message sent for each conversation

Comment: have created the conversation table.. the update here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick only username from users table by `from_user_id` this will help you.

```
SELECT username
FROM users INNER JOIN messages ON messages.from_user_id=users.id 
WHERE from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```